# Merge fields do not appear when sending an email with apex using a template

Tags: email, salesforce, apex, email-templates, salesforce-communities

I am sending a template email to some users, the template contains a merge field {{!Opportunity.custom__c}}. When sending it, the value of the field does not appear.

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    email.setTemplateId(et.Id); // Email Template ID
    email.setTargetObjectId(user.Id); // User ID to send
    //email.setWhatId(opp.Id); !Error!
    email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
    emails.add(email);
```

So I want to know if there is any way to pass information about the opportunity to the template?
Shouldn't I use a template?

I have searched and they say to add email.setWhatId(opportunity.Id), when adding it it gives me the following error: INVALID_ID_FIELD, WhatId is not available for sending emails to UserIds.: [whatId, XXXXXXXXXXX].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because the method notification.setTargetObjectId(usr.Id) uses User Id and as per documentation you need to use notification.setWhatId(updatedOpp.Id) only when setTargetObjectId is contact.

Refer documentation below

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setWhatId.htm

I don't think you can achieve this without custom coding the message. public Void setHtmlBody(String htmlBody) I would try and use this instead of the templates.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your usage, it looks like you used User for setTargetObjectId.
For classic templates, this is fine if you're using Lead, Contact, etc, but if you put User as the Target, you're limited to using WhatId.

There have been various attempts to address this over 15 years ago.
Salesforce hasn't fixed it themselves, so there are only two solutions: work around it or use other features.

First, the classic internal workaround is to use the Contact Id to solve the problem.
The solution is to create a Contact with the same email address, send it, and then delete it immediately, as shown below.

```
Contact ct = new Contact(Email = user.Email, LastName = "Name");
insert ct;
mail.setTargetObjectId(ct.Id);
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
delete ct;
```

The second method is to create template with Visualforce.
Visualforce templates, even Classic ones, have a recipientType and a relatedToType inside.
The recipientType specifies the recipient related object and the relatedToType specifies the Target Object.

You can create a template as shown below and then access the fields in the record with recipient, relatedTo.

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="any subject" recipientType="User" relatedToType="ObjectName">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
    <html> 
        <body> 
            Dear {!recipient.Name}
            Target Name : {!relatedTo.Name}
        </body> 
    </html> 
</messaging:htmlEmailBody> 
</messaging:emailTemplate>

-------------------------------------------

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
mail.setSaveAsActivity(false); 
mail.setBccSender(false);
mail.setUseSignature(false);
mail.setTemplateId(template.Id); 
mail.setWhatId (targetObject.Id);
mail.setTargetObjectId(targetObject.Owner.Id);
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

Good Luck